# how to add, update, delete and search object inside array of objects

Tags: javascript

Hello I have an empty array, then I push inside objects, but is not getting updated, it going back to empty again. this on node.js. i need to get as the first argument - from the commend line one of three string that do something to the array : 'add' to add new item to the array, 'delete' for delete frm the array and and 'update' for update the array . second argument is name of the book,third argument author, and last arugmnt pages.

```
    let arrayOfBooks = [];

// Assign places to the array 
let whichArgument = process.argv[2]
let name = process.argv[3];
let author = process.argv[4];
let pages = Number(process.argv[5]);

// Function constructor
function Book(name,author,pages) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
}

// Add function
const addBook = (arrayOfBooks)=> {
    arrayOfBooks.push(new Book(name, author, pages));
    return arrayOfBooks
}
let result = addBook(arrayOfBooks);
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? When I try it in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/XWWqOBY) it works.

Comment: You need to learn more about debugging JS code. take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot to mention that it is on node.js. let me update the code. and restate the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works, but maybe you are loosing the reference by using the same name to the array and the params. But anyway, as the method `.push` does not return an updated array, just it modifies the same array instance, you don't need to return the pushed array, just use it.

```js
const arrayOfBooks = [
    {book: 1},
  {book: 2},
  {book: 3},
  {book: 4},
]

const addBook = (list, book) => {
    list.push(book)
}

addBook(arrayOfBooks, {book: 5, isTheNewOne: true})

const result = arrayOfBooks
console.log(result)
// Array with 5 elements now
```

See in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lfernandosilva/x7g3sahL/2/)